# Change text of Full Calendar Select Helper Event

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I just wanna to change the text that appears when select periods of time. Here is the jQuery:

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    header: {
      center: 'title',
      left: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
    },
    minTime: '07:00:00',
    maxTime: '22:00:00',
    hiddenDays: [0],
    weekends: true,
    fixedWeekCount: false,
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    defaultView: 'agendaDay',
    allDaySlot: true,
    timeFormat: 'H:mm',
    allDayText: 'Funcionários:'
});
```

This is the result:
[image: Change Text]

I just want to change the circulating red text. Can anyone help me?

PS: Anyone knows how to be able to select multiple periods of time in the same day?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You want to change the circulating red text to what? And the info that you've provided looks not enough.

Comment: @5ervant I wanna change it to a string, what more you need?

Comment: Is this the correct code? How are you pulling your event objects?

Comment: via ajax and refreshing the calendar..

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar situation and I managed to change the selecthelper event of fullcalendar by looking for the .fc-helper class in eventRender:

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {

    if (element.find(".fc-helper")){
        element.find(".fc-time").text(your-string);

    }
```

Please mind that js is really new to me so don't assume the code is correct. It works though.